# Windows Service needs to restart to keep its functioning

Tags: c#, email, windows-services

I have created a windows service that sends email reminders every 30 seconds. 10 days before it was working fine but now it doesn't run until it is restarted manually from services.msc

Once it is restarted, the service then sends email.

The window service is written in C# and in Visual Studio 2005.

Let me know if any info needed.

Thanks for your inputs!

**UPDATED:Event viewer error descripition**

Timestamp: 4/5/2011 6:03:53 AM 
Message: There is no explicit mapping for the categories 'Application'. 
The log entry was: 
Timestamp: 4/5/2011 6:03:53 AM
Message: Error Type: ERR_RETRIEVING_DATA
Entity Information: Get 
Session Info: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Category: Application
Priority: -1
EventId: 0
Severity: Information
Title:
Machine: VPS
App Domain: EinsteinEMRServerSetupSupport.exe
ProcessId: 3660
Process Name: C:\SOAPe Platinum Plus\EinsteinEMRServerSetupSupport.exe
Thread Name: 
Win32 ThreadId:3680
Extended Properties: 
Category: 
Priority: -1
EventId: 6352
Severity: Error
Title:
Machine: VPS
Application Domain: EinsteinEMRServerSetupSupport.exe 
Process Id: 3660
Process Name: C:\SOAPe Platinum Plus\EinsteinEMRServerSetupSupport.exe
Win32 Thread Id: 3680
Thread Name: 
Extended Properties:

Comment: "It doesn't work" is pretty vague. Presumably *something's* gone wrong, but we can't possibly tell what from that description. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many times for windows services' problems, looking at windows event's logs enables to target disfunction, but as said by Jon Skeet : Hard to give you more precise orientation without details.

Comment: let me know the details required to get out of this problem

Comment: You should add detailed logging to your service.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, `ERR_RETRIEVING_DATA` seems a bit tricky. Sounds like a I/O problems on hard drive  (due to termination), but strange to see it works after a restart. It could be anything in the system.

What is the information you're trying to get ?
How do you try to get it ?

Does your problem appears after a reboot of the machine ? 
 Wouldn't it be because of your service's list start order ?

If "Your" service start before the resources that it needs, you would be unable to reach it (For example, starting before MSMQ while trying to push/get messages).